AppleScript not reading environmental variable
I've set at the end ~/.bash_profile a new environmental variable like so:
# [...]
# Test
export PIPPO=passwordTest

Saved the file and defined the following AppleScript
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set envVarName to "PIPPO"
    set varname to system attribute envVarName
    log varname
    # [...]
end tell

The problem is that the log shows empty string. If I change "PIPPO" to "HOME", the log correctly shows the $HOME env variable. What could be wrong?
Thank you!

The shell (and environment) that applescript uses is not the same as what Terminal uses. Your variable only exists in the wrong environment. Run env in the terminal and then run do shell script "env" in an applescript and compare. Then make the last line in your script system attribute and compare the result to the two environments. You can find out more in tech note 2065.

I elaborated a bit here: AppleScript do shell script returns error for "which" command. Nobody has commented on it so perhaps it is reasonably sound.

Thank you very much, that is all clear to me! I am now wondering how I can set an env variable that is readable from the script without setting it in the script itself: I am trying to fetch a password and I do not want to write it in clear on the script...

Not sure I can help you with that. It's probably a separate question. You should be able to modify the environment from within either the applescript or the terminal.
